# How can I scrape all articles from a URL

Tags: python, web-scraping

New to Python, and I am trying to scrape a specific website and I am having trouble. I am trying to scrape articles from "https://www.cnn.com/business" but what is happening is that I am scraping "cnn.com" and grabbing all these articles instead. Is there a way to scrape just the business section of the website? 
If my approach is completely wrong, I'd love to know what would be the better way to do this. Thanks

I have a json file that has link to cnn.com/business, and I am using the newspaper library in Python

```
#!pip install feedparser
#!pip install newspaper3k

import feedparser as fp
import numpy as np
import json
import newspaper
from newspaper import Article
from time import mktime
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import csv

# Set the limit for number of articles to download
LIMIT = 10
articles_array = []

data = {}
data['newspapers'] = {}

# Loads the JSON files with news sites
with open('newspapers.json') as data_file:
    companies = json.load(data_file)


paper = newspaper.build(value['link'], memoize_articles=False)
newsPaper = {
    "link": value['link'],
    "articles": [],
}
noneTypeCount = 0
for content in paper.articles:
    if count > LIMIT:
        break
    try:
        content.download()
        content.parse()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("continuing...")
        continue

article = {}
article['title'] = content.title
article['authors'] = content.authors
article['text'] = content.text
article['top_image'] =  content.top_image
article['link'] = content.url
article['published'] = content.publish_date
newsPaper['articles'].append(article)
articles_array.append(article)       
print(count, "articles downloaded from", company, " using newspaper, url: ", content.url)
count = count + 1
#noneTypeCount = 0
count = 1
data['newspapers'][company] = newsPaper
```

Comment: I would suggest checking the attributes exposed by this newspaper library to see what it can do. But seeing as it may be a generic library, it doesn't understand that CNN even has a business section, compared to beautifulsoup where you have to specify what section of the page to parse

Comment: Are you intending on scraping the entire text from each of the links on the left hand side of that initial landing page?

Answer (score 1):

This is more likely a comment rather than a full post.

```
    import urllib
    import re
    NUM_LINKS_YOU_WANT = 10
    urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://edition.cnn.com/business", ".temp_file")
    occurrences = []
    for line in open(".temp_file"):
        if "index.html" in line:
            occurrences.append(line)
    positions = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('index.html', occurrences[-1])]
    line = occurrences[-1]
    links = []
    for p in positions:
        href = line[0:p].rfind("href")
        links.append(" https://edition.cnn.com"+line[href+6:p])
    print(links[0:NUM_LINKS_YOU_WANT])
```